# How to call Google Distance api from android app using Android key?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

We are using Google Distance Matrix API to show the travel distance between user current location and destination point in an activity which show Google map as well. We are using following url with Android key generated using app package and sha1 of debug.keystore.

// Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," +              origin.longitude;

```
    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

    // String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&";
    // Output format
    String output = "json";

String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/" + output +"?"
                + parameters + "&mode=walking&key=" +"Android_Key";
```

But the above url gives following reponse,

```
{"destination_addresses" : [],   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address *.*.*.*, with empty referer",   "origin_addresses" : [],   "rows" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

What wrong am doing here?.It works with android key which not mapped to app package name and sha1.

Answer (score -2):

API_KEY is not the necessary requirement while using various Google Maps API. I tested this REST API call for distance Matrix API without the API key in the *Advanced REST Client* and was successfully able to receive a 200 OK response.

Here is the request:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling
```

And here is the response:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "San Francisco, CA, USA", "Victoria, BC, Canada" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Vancouver, BC, Canada", "Seattle, WA, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,706 km",
                  "value" : 1705627
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 days 19 hours",
                  "value" : 327067
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "139 km",
                  "value" : 138549
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "6 hours 42 mins",
                  "value" : 24146
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,449 km",
                  "value" : 1449084
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 days 4 hours",
                  "value" : 274649
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "146 km",
                  "value" : 146496
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 hours 52 mins",
                  "value" : 10324
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

This means the even if you do not put an API_KEY in your request call you would be able to get a successful response. As per the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters) **This key identifies your application for purposes of quota management**. So if you are able to support a very large userbase, you should use the API_KEY and request additional quota.

Comment: In case we are able to support a large user base then what should we do?
Adding API key will respond with an error message..!